# Removing button for users

Tags: javascript, django

My website has user login and registarion. I wanted to remove login and register button for a user that is logged inn and remove the logout button for a user that is logged out. Im doing this in JavaScript but i can seem to get it to work.

```
var user = "{{ request.user }}"

 if (user != 'AnonymousUser'){
            btn = document.getElementsByClassName('user-out');
            for(i=0; i<btn.length; i++){
                btn[i].remove();
                //OR
                btn[i].classList.add('hidden');
            }
        }
        if (user == 'AnonymousUser'){
            document.getElementById('user-in').classList.add('hidden')
        }
```

Im using Django in my backend. This is the HTML code.

```
<a href="{% url 'login' %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary user-out">Logg Inn</button></a>

<a href="{% url 'reg' %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success user-out">Registrer deg</button></a>

<a href="{% url 'logout' %}"><button id = "user-in" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Logg Ut</button></a>
```

Comment: You have typos, is it `user-in` or `user-inn` ?... also the second `if` condition does not do anything to `btn`, it just assigns a value to it, I believe you want to remove `"btn"` in the same way the first `if` condition is doing, either by `remove()` or adding the `"hidden"` class

Comment: Ye that was a typo, and i fixed the second if, but it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check this `user.is_authenticated` and see if user is authenticated and I suppose that you have access to the `user` object as well.
I usually do the same thing using below code to do the same thing:

`{% if user.is_authenticated %}`

In your scenario you can do the same. Also check that you get the right value by `consol.log(user)` .